# ng-class conditional doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-class

I have an angular directive named fund. The directive is defined as follows.

```
return{
  restrict: 'E',
  replace: true,
  scope: {
    data: '=',
    cut: '@'
    },
  templateUrl: 'app/directives/partials/fund.jsp'
}
```

It has a property named `cut`. If cut is set, I will apply `text-cut` class, and if not set, no class. The class is as follows in case needed:

```
.text-cut{
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  text-overflow: ellipsis
}
```

I have tried the using the directive as:

```
<fund data="myCtrl.fundList" cut="true"></fund>

<fund data="myCtrl.fundList" cut="'true'"></fund>
```

with following  ng-class attributes in the template:

```
ng-class="text-cut: cut"
ng-class="text-cut: 'cut'"
ng-class="{text-cut: cut}"
ng-class="{text-cut: 'cut'}"
ng-class="text-cut: cut===true"
ng-class="text-cut: 'cut'===true"
ng-class="{text-cut: cut===true}"
ng-class="{text-cut: 'cut'===true}"
```

But none of these combinations applied `text-cut` class to my fund directive. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to quote `text-cut`. Try

```
ng-class="{'text-cut': cut}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that returns the string class you want based on some condition. Then call it in your ng-class. As long as the function returns the css you want it should work.

```
$scope.checkCut = function(){
   if(this.cut != null){
      return 'text-cut';
   }
}
```

In your directive

```
 ng-class="checkCut"
```